# Counting the number of words of a fixed length, where the number of times each character appears across all words is bounded

Tags: combinatorics, information-theory, coding-theory, combinatorics-on-words

Suppose I have an alphabet of $k$ characters, like $\Sigma = \lbrace a, b, c, d, e \rbrace$. I want to build words of length $m$, but I have a fixed budget for each character. The letter $a$ appears at most $m*n_a$ times, the letter $b$ at most $m*n_b$ times, etc., *across all words*. For example, if $n_a = 1$, then I can only have one word that begins with "a", one word that has "a" in the second position, etc. (and these don't have to be separate words)

**How many unique words can I create of length $m$?**

Clearly for large enough $n_i$ and small enough $m$, we have that this is simply $|\Sigma|^m$.

Another simple version of this, is where I have a binary alphabet {0, 1}, and have, say, $n_0 = m/3$. Then at most a third of any of the characters in our word are zeros, so the total words can be counted by the partial binomial sum $\sum_{i=0}^{m/3} \binom{m}{i}$, summing up to the integer part of $m/3$.

*Edit:* Another way to phrase this is suppose we have $m$ identical but ordered urns. Each urn is filled with balls of $k$ different colors, with $n_i$ (indistinguishable) balls per color, $i = 0, 1, ..., k$. Drawing from each urn simultaneously without replacement, how many unique sequences can we draw from these urns?